# Creation-Annihilation operators and Young diagrams

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, young-tableaux

Let assume a Fock space written as,
$$F=\bigoplus_\rho V_\rho,$$
where $V_\rho$ is an irreducible representation of $U(N)$ labeled by a partition (Young diagram) $\rho$. For the so-called bosonic case we have only single-row diagrams whereas for the fermionic case there is only single-column contributions to the expansion.

In both cases is possible to define creation-annihilation operators acting on the number-representation basis (semi-standard Young tableaux SSYT for each $\rho$) in such a way that it is possible to move one vector in this basis from one irreducible vector space to any other one in the direct sum. However, if we are working in a general expansion, where the contributions might be neither bosonic nor fermionic, it is still possible to define creation-annihilation operators? For example, to map a SSYT in representation (1) to (2,1) as we can do it from (1) to (3) or from (1) to (1,1,1) using bosonic operators or fermionic operators, respectively?

Comment: I think the answer is yes, but for clarity do you have a reference for what this Fock space is, and what you consider to be annihilation/creation operators? There are about a zillion things which people call "Fock space"...

Comment: Is my interpretation of the Fock space based on the fact that each term in the direct sum is an irrep of $U(n)$.

Comment: There is a space that you're describing, which at least in the algebraic case (replacing $\operatorname{U}(n)$ by $\operatorname{GL}_n$ and replacing "smooth representation" with "algebraic representation") is isomorphic to the homogeneous coordinate ring of the flag variety $\operatorname{GL}_n / B$, where $B$ is the subgroup of upper-triangular matrices. This space is sometimes also called the "Plücker algebra", and is isomorphic to a direct sum of every irrep of $\operatorname{GL}_n$. I'm not sure what you want out of creation and annihilation operators though, hence the question.